# Setting an object instance to an instance of another object not working

Tags: c#, object, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm basically Passing a object through a form constructor and then I try setting another object to the instance of the parsed object doesn't work the value stays null please note that this code worked on a different content page. Only difference is I'm binding to entries instead of labels.

```cs
public partial class CatoSelectUWP : ContentPage
    {
        public static Product prod;

        public CatoSelectUWP(Product product)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            App.isHandeled = true;
            prod = product;
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            pcodetxt.Text = prod.PROD.ToString();
            desctxt.Text = prod.PDSC.ToString();
            brndtxtUWP.Text = prod.PBRN.ToString();
            coltxtuwp.Text = prod.PCOL.ToString();
            packtxtuwp.Text = prod.PPCD.ToString();
            sellingtxtUWP.Text = prod.SELL.ToString();
            iqtytxt.Text = prod.IQTY.ToString();
            pskutxtUWP.Text = prod.PSKU.ToString();
            sizetxtUWP.Text = prod.PSZE.ToString();
            App.isHandeled = false;
        }


    }
```

prod should contain the values of the passed product.

What seems to be happening is the application goes back to the original page multiple times and then when it stop the product is now null.

### Previous page selection code

```cs
 private async void LVUWP_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (stat == false&& App.isHandeled == false)
                {
                    var obj = (Product)e.SelectedItem;
                    Product prodselect = new Product(obj.PROD, obj.DPID, obj.SDID, obj.CGID, obj.SCID, obj.PDSC, obj.PBRN,
                        obj.SESN, obj.IQTY, obj.CURR, obj.SELL, obj.PSKU, obj.PSZE, obj.PCOL, obj.PPCD, obj.DPDS);

                    App.isHandeled = true;

                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new CatoSelectUWP(prodselect));

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

### Xaml

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>

        <ScrollView>

            <StackLayout Margin="20">

                <StackLayout>

                    <Image
                        Aspect="AspectFit"
                        HeightRequest="300"
                        Source="shoe1.jpg"
                        WidthRequest="300" />

                </StackLayout>



                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Vertical">

                    <Label
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                        Text="Product Code:"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}" />

                    <Entry
                        x:Name="pcodetxt"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsEnabled="False"
                        Text="Product Code"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}"
                        WidthRequest="500" />

                    <Label
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Text="Description:"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}" />

                    <Entry
                        x:Name="desctxt"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsEnabled="False"
                        Text="Description"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}"
                        WidthRequest="500" />

                    <Label
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Text="Brand:"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}" />

                    <Entry
                        x:Name="brndtxtUWP"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsEnabled="False"
                        Text="Brand"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}"
                        WidthRequest="500" />

                    <Label
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Text="Colours Available:"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}" />

                    <Entry
                        x:Name="coltxtuwp"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsEnabled="False"
                        Text="Colours Available"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}"
                        WidthRequest="500" />

                    <Label
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Text="Available Packs:"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}" />

                    <Entry
                        x:Name="packtxtuwp"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsEnabled="False"
                        Text="Available Packs"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}"
                        WidthRequest="500" />

                    <Label
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Text="selling Price:"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}" />

                    <Entry
                        x:Name="sellingtxtUWP"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsEnabled="False"
                        Text="Unit Price"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}"
                        WidthRequest="500" />

                    <Label
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Text="Issue Quantity:"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}" />

                    <Entry
                        x:Name="iqtytxt"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsEnabled="False"
                        Text="Unit Price"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}"
                        WidthRequest="500" />

                    <Label
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Text="Product SKU:"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}" />

                    <Entry
                        x:Name="pskutxtUWP"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsEnabled="False"
                        Text="Unit Price"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}"
                        WidthRequest="500" />

                    <Label
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Text="Sizes:"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}" />

                    <Entry
                        x:Name="sizetxtUWP"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsEnabled="False"
                        Text="Unit Price"
                        TextColor="{x:StaticResource Key=ColorBlue}"
                        WidthRequest="500" />



                </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

### What seems to happening

I set breakpoint to explain what happens is the product get the correct values and then for some reason returns to the

```cs
 await Navigation.PushAsync(new CatoSelectUWP(prodselect));
```

line of code multiple times and then when it stops the product is empty again

### Solved

While scanning the code I noticed there was a second event that handles the tapping of the view cell item this is what went wrong and I've fixed the problem by deleting the second event handler.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you're doing here. Objects are Reference types, i.e.  they always get passed around using pointers. Your GetProd function simply returns the same reference you passed in to it.

Comment: `public static Product prod` field not need to be  `static` ?

Comment: I'm basically trying to take the parsed product and take a product object on the form and set its values to the values of the parsed product

Comment: @Fatcatfats - There's no parsing going on in your code. What part do you think is parsing?

Comment: Passing of the object through the page constructor sorry.

Comment: @Fatcatfats - Are you saying that the bit that's not working is the constructor of `Product`?

Comment: I don't really know what's going wrong cause on a different form I've done exactly the same thing and it works but for some reason with this form it doesn't want to work. Note this form runs on UWP and the working form android.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is something odd with your implementation, since in the else statement:

```
 else if (stat == true && App.isHandeled == false)
            {
                var obj = (Product)e.SelectedItem;
                App.isHandeled = true;
                Product prodselect = new Product(obj.PROD, obj.DPID, obj.SDID, obj.CGID, obj.SCID, obj.PDSC, obj.PBRN,
                    obj.SESN, obj.IQTY, obj.CURR, obj.SELL, obj.PSKU, obj.PSZE, obj.PCOL, obj.PPCD, obj.DPDS);
```

you are doing nothing with prodselect...

It will be very hard to guess what you are trying to achieve without further about the xaml itself.

Try to be more objective, set a break point.

Comment: That code is for a different part of the app that's not done yet that's why it does nothing yet.

Comment: @Fatcatfats - Why is it in your question then?

Comment: This isn't really an answer. It's just a comment with code.

Comment: @Enigmativity that is why comments doesn't allow indentation, so, it was not meant to gain points, just to help the user and clarify... unless there is a nicer and cleaner way to show code example in comments...